# List in Linq where condition

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to get records which satisfies certain list of values.

```
var batch_institute = (from tb in context.tblBatch_Institute
                                            where tb.BatchID == model.BatchID
                                            select tb);

var currentMaxBatchNo = (from tb in context.tblBatches
                                              join tbins in context.tblBatch_Institute on tb.BatchID equals tbins.BatchID
                                              where tb.AcadamicSemester == batch.AcadamicSemester && tb.AcadamicYear == batch.AcadamicYear
                                              && tb.CampusID == batch.CampusID && tb.FacultyID == batch.FacultyID && tb.IntakeID == batch.IntakeID &&
                                              tb.IntakeYear == batch.IntakeYear && tb.Weekend_Day == batch.Weekend_Day
                                              && batch_institute.Any(code => tbins.InstituteID.Equals(code))
                                              select tbins);
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with the below code in the second linq query

```
batch_institute.Any(code => tbins.InstituteID.Equals(code))
```

I'm getting error below.

> DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types

Answer (score 0):

The first query returns a collection of rows from the `tblBatch_Institute` table.

But then you're trying to compare rows to individual `InstituteID` values in the second query.

Modify your first query to only return `InstituteID` values, like this:

```
var batch_institute_ids = (from tb in context.tblBatch_Institute
                           where tb.BatchID == model.BatchID
                           select tb.InstituteID);
```

Then the following comparison should work:

```
batch_institute_ids.Any(id => tbins.InstituteID.Equals(id))
```

You may be able to alter that second query to use this instead, assuming EF is capable of converting it to a valid SQL query.

```
batch_institute_ids.Contains(tbins.InstituteID)
```